# Misunderstanding about a problem in algorithms

Tags: algorithms

> Consider the following sequence
> $$\mathcal{S}=\langle3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,8,9,7,9,3,2,3,8,4,6,2,7,9\rangle$$ We can imagine
> some adjacent elements of $\mathcal{S}$ as a number. For example,
> $5$, and 3 and $8$ form the number $538$. We say two number in above
> format is disjoint, if there is nothing common element between them.
> With respect to $\mathcal{S}$, what is  the maximum number of disjoint
> numbers we can make such that have increasing order from left to right?

I think if we consider only numbers with $1$ digit, then we have at most nine numbers that have no common element and sorted in increasing order from left to right. But the answer is $10$ numbers. Maybe i have a misunderstanding about the problem, so any one have a idea to clarify me that why answer become $10$?

Comment: Unless there is something wrong with my understanding of the statement, the answer cannot be 9 either. If it were 9 then we would need to use each digit between $1$ and $9$ exactly once. However there is no way to select 9 digits with this property from $\mathcal{S}$. For example you can see that there are only two occurrences of $5$. The first can't be selected since there is no $2$ before it. The second occurrence cannot be selected since there is no $3$ between the only previous occurrence of a $2$ and this second occurrence of $5$.

Comment: If to assume, that we can skip digits, the answer is $(3,4,5,9,26,53,89,93,238,462)$

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  We require you to credit the source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: @HEKTO 89, and 93 have common element 9.

Comment: I assumed, that the "common element" meant something else. For example, numbers 314 and 415 have common digit 4. The problem statement is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably asking you to select a collection of numbers that can be formed from pairwise disjoint contiguous groups of $k$ digits from $\mathcal{S}$ and such the obtained numbers are  **non-decreasing**  (and not **increasing** as written in the statement!) when the associated groups are considered from left to right.
The goal is to select as many numbers as possible.

Then, for $k=1$, a feasible solution (I didn't check if it is optimal) selects $10$ numbers, highlighted in bold:

$$
\langle 3,\textbf{1},4,\textbf{1},5,9,\textbf{2},6,5,\textbf{3},8,9,7,9,\textbf{3},2,\textbf{3},8,\textbf{4},\textbf{6},2,\textbf{7},\textbf{9}\rangle
$$

Comment: 1,1 that you choose have common element 1.

Comment: It is not the same occurrence of $1$. The selected groups of digits from $S$ are still pairwise disjoint.